# Changing this Quicksort implementation's comparator from <= to < causes infinite recursion. Why?

Tags: java, algorithm, sorting, recursion, quicksort

I'm studying the Quicksort implementation below (from Cracking the Coding Interview).

In the partition method, there are two "left <= right" predicates (in its first while-statement and last if-statement). When left == right, swapping elements at these indices would be the same as no swap, so I thought removing the "==" part of the comparison would not have any effect. However, when I do this and run the code instead with "left < right", the program recurses infinitely (on certain inputs) and results in a stack overflow. Why?

Clarification: I am updating both "left <= right" predicates to "left < right" in the partition method, in the (1) first while-statement and (2) final if-statement.

Otherwise, the solution works fine when using "left <= right".

P.S. Since "left" gets incremented in the last if-statement, I did also try returning left+1, but this still can result in infinite recursion.

```
public static void quickSort(int[] arr, int left, int right) {
    int index = partition(arr, left, right);
    if (left < index - 1) { // Sort left half
        quickSort(arr, left, index - 1);
    }
    if (index < right) { // Sort right half
        quickSort(arr, index, right);
    }
}

public static int partition(int[] arr, int left, int right) {
    int pivot = arr[(left + right) / 2]; // Pick a pivot point. Can be an element        
    while (left <= right) {
        // Find element on left that should be on right
        while (arr[left] < pivot) { 
            left++;
        }

        // Find element on right that should be on left
        while (arr[right] > pivot) {
            right--;
        }

        // Swap elements, and move left and right indices
        if (left <= right) {
            swap(arr, left, right);
            left++;
            right--;
        }
    }
    return left; 
}

public static void swap(int[] array, int i, int j) {
    int tmp = array[i];
    array[i] = array[j];
    array[j] = tmp;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's take simple example where array to be sorted is `{1, 2}`. When `quicksort` is called for first time `left` is `0`, `right` is `1`. Those values will be forwarded to `partition` where `pivot` will be `1`. Since `arr[right] > pivot` `right` will be decremented but `left` remains the same.

Since at the end of the `while` loop in partition `left < right` is false nothing is swapped and loop will exit since it has the same condition. `partition` will return `left` which is 0 and is assigned to `index`.

Next `quicksort` will skip the first branch since `left < index - 1` is false. The second branch will be executed since `index < right` and there `quicksort` is called `index` and `right` whose values are `0` and `1` respectively. Now if we go at the beginning we see that `quicksort` was initially called with exactly same values which explains the infinite recursion.

If you return `left + 1` instead then `index` will be 2 after first partition with input `{1, 1}` and you will have exactly same issue with first branch in `quicksort`.

Comment: This is the correct answer, and you helped me realize I was asking the wrong question.. what I really wanted to know is how this solution was derived / why it un-intuitively uses the <= operator and not the < operator.  I am guessing this probably has more to do with the derivation of the Hoare partition method.. in any case, no fault of your own! :-)